# Как сохранить данные в базу данных?

Tags: php, yii2

Пишу парсер который сохраняет со стороннего сайта данные. По введенному адресу страницы 
получаю **маcсив** такого вида:

```
array(1) {
    ['category']=>"lorem ipsum"
    ['description']=>'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.'
    ['page']=>'За словесными горами ';
    ['desc_page']=>'Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана.'
};
```

Ну и поскольку категории могут повторятся у разных страниц вопрос:

Как мне правильно оформить сохранение в базу в случае отсутствие в базе категории с названием `"lorem ipsum"`?

Comment: что такое правильно? если не писать явный запрос на проверку, значить писать триггер, который добавит отсутствующую категорию и подставит её id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
    $categoryId = Category::find()
      ->select('id')
      ->where(['title'=>"lorem ipsum"])
      ->scalar();

    if (!$categoryId ){
       $newCategory = new Category();
       $newCategory->setAttributes(
            ['title'=>"lorem ipsum"]
       );
       if($newCategory->save()){
           $categoryId = $newCategory->id;
       }
    }
```